# Need to press 2 times a button to have the right video playing

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have a view with a series of action buttons. All these buttons are connected to a function that allows me to play a video. I retrieve the name of the video in the button title. The problem is that I need to press the button twice to get the right video, otherwise the last video is playing
Here is the code that is associated.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class levresViewController:    UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
var varVue2="toto"
var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
var player:AVPlayer?


   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     let videoString:String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: varVue2,   ofType: ".mp4")
    if let url = videoString {
        let videoURL=NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
        self.playerController.player = self.player
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


     @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
      varVue2=sender.currentTitle!

      self.present(self.playerController,animated:true,completion:{
        self.playerController.player?.play()
       })

   }
}
```